# strust2.5 exception-mapping not worked

Tags: java, servlets, struts

I used Struts 2.5.16,follow code is struts.xml content:

```
<package name="default" extends="struts-default">
    <interceptors>
        <interceptor  name="authorizeInterceptor" class="web.comm.Interceptor.authorizeInterceptor"></interceptor>
    </interceptors>
    <action name="home">
        <result type="dispatcher">/view/index.jsp</result>
    </action>
    <action name="exp" class="web.comm.userAndAuthorize.commUserOp" method="jsonChangePass">
        <interceptor-ref name="authorizeInterceptor"/> 
        <exception-mapping result="Exception" exception="java.lang.Exception"/>
        <result name="Exception"  type="chain">/view/UserAndAuthorize/error.jsp</result>
        <allowed-methods>jsonChkLogin,jsonChangePass,createUser</allowed-methods>
    </action>
```

url is http://localhost/exp
follow code is method of jsonChangePass()

```
public String jsonChangePass()throws Exception{

    int b=0,a=1;
    int c=a/b;
```

follow content is chorme showed:

> Struts Problem Report Struts has detected an unhandled exception:
>
> Messages:  / by zero ......

---

see the web showing content, action is already working.why the exception-mapping not worked?thanks for ervery one help.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're not running the `exception` mapping interceptor, it won't work.

Once you define `<interceptors>` in a package you must define *all* the interceptors: this is not an additive element, this is a declaration of the interceptors used in that package.

IIRC you can use an `<interceptor-ref>` to get the `defaultStack` (or whichever you actually intended to use) and add your `authorizeInterceptor`.

Comment: Thanks,i understanded!!